# Colspan in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to get colspan working in XSLT but it just will not work for me...here is what I have please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="colspan-2">
    <xsl:attribute name="colspan">2</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="valign-c title border colspan-2">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="data"/>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

My other attributes work fine, but colspan-1 causes everything to fail.  Seems to me like this should work, but it not.  I am probably missing something silly, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "causes everything to fail" mean?

Comment: Sorry to be more description, it throws the very helpful "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error." I get when I have in correct XSLT.

Comment: Doesn't XSLFO use `number-columns-spanned` and not `colspan`?

Comment: you are right!! my bad...if you put that as an answer I will accept! That fixed it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't confuse XSL-FO with HTML.

HTML uses `colspan`

XSL-FO uses `number-columns-spanned`

So, if you try replace `colspan` with `number-columns-spanned` then all should be well.